# How to print out a text once grunt task completes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Once a Grunt task completes, I want to print out some information. See the Grunt snippet below.

Is there a way to achieve this? I noticed that `grunt.task.run()` does not support callbacks. This causes my message to be printed out prior to coverage report output.

```
grunt.registerTask('coverage', 'Runs all unit tests available via Mocha and generates code coverage report', function() {
    grunt.task.run('env:unitTest', 'mochaTest');

    grunt.log.writeln('Code coverage report was generated into "build/coverage.html"');
});
```

I also want to avoid "hacks" such as creating a grunt task only for printing the information out and adding it to the `grunt.task.run()` chain of tasks.

Comment: shouldnt every task itself be responsible for the information it wants to print out???

Comment: Yes, that would be an ideal way. The problem is that the code coverage task which is a Grunt module, does not have an option to give it some text message to be printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a much better way to do it, without creating an extra task, and modifying anything else.

Grunt is a node process, so you can:

- use the process `stdout` to write what you need
- subscribe to the process `exit` event to do it when a task is finishing its execution

This is a simple example which prints out the time when the tasks has finished their execution:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // Creates a write function bound to process.stdout:
    var write = process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout);

    // Subscribes to the process exit event...
    process.on("exit", function () {
        // ... to write the information in the process stdout
        write('\nFinished at ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString()+ '\n');
    });

    // From here, your usual gruntfile configuration, without changes
    grunt.initConfig({
```

When you run any task, you'll see a message at the bottom like:

> Finished at 18:26:45

Answer (score 19):

Create a task that will run when everything is all done and then add it to your task chain:

```
grunt.registerTask('alldone', function() {
  grunt.log.writeln('Code coverage report was generated into "build/coverage.html"');
});
grunt.registerTask('default', ['env:unitTest', 'mochaTest', 'alldone']);
```

Comment: Well, I wanted to avoid such workaround by creating special task just to print out an information. However, I ended up doing that anyway as haven't found a better way yet :(

Comment: I've struggled with this, too. I assume there's a good reason for not allowing users to include function calls in the dependency list... I'm not happy about it, but my solve was a bash script which does before and after logging around my task.

Comment: Grunt is a javascript task runner so the best answer to almost every question regarding how to do something in Grunt is: use a task.